# Ruby printing out hash data

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working on a database that holds records for a school, where the key is the studentID, followed by the values of, first name, last name, major, and catalog year. I am working on the display function, which loops through the users which have been added to the hash. however, my code is not printing out of all the records i have added to the database.

it is only printing out one record listing, rather than my multiple inputted entries.

here is an example of input:
    -----------------------------
    Student Database Records
    -----------------------------

```
1) Insert new record to database
2) Modify record in database
3) Remove record from database
4) Display record(s) in database
5) Quit
6) Enter choice:
1

-----------------------------
Add Record(s)
-----------------------------

Enter Student Identifcation Number:
32424

Enter First name of Student:
sfsdf

Enter Last name of Student:
sdfsfsf

Enter Major of Student:
sdfsdfs

Enter Catalogue Year:
sdfsfds

Your entry for Student ID 32424 has been added to the database.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
32424: sfsdf, sdfsfsf, sdfsdfs, sdfsfds
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here is my code to add an array to a hash

```
    student_id = gets().chomp


    if school_database.sDB.has_key?(student_id)
        puts "Student Record Already Existent"
        return school_database
    end 

    puts "\nEnter First name of Student: "
    first_name = gets().chomp

    puts "\nEnter Last name of Student: "
    last_name = gets().chomp

    puts "\nEnter Major of Student: "
    major = gets().chomp

    puts "\nEnter Catalogue Year: "
    catalogue_year = gets().chomp

    puts "\nYour entry for Student ID #{student_id} has been added to the database.\n"

    puts "\n------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    puts "#{student_id}: #{first_name}, #{last_name}, #{major}, #{catalogue_year}"
    puts "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"

    store_account_data =  first_name + "," + last_name + "," + major + "," + catalogue_year

    school_database.sDB[student_id] = [store_account_data]

    return school_database
```

here is the code i am using to loop through my hash to print out the records.

```
school_database.sDB.each do |key, store_account_data|
puts "\n"
puts "#{key}: #{store_account_data.join(',')}"
```

positively, I run the .size command, and i discovered that it is adding muliple entries to the hash, however, it is not printing all of them

any ideas?

Comment: What data types are `key` and `store_account_data` (I assume at least one is an `Array`, but of what?)? Can you show examples?

Comment: @lurker just numbers and letters

32424: Matthew, Arnold, CIT, 2015

i modified my post to show you how the input works! :)

Answer (score 2):

String’s `+` method places fairly strict requirements on what can appear on the right-hand side. You need to explicitly call `to_s`:

```
puts key + ' : ' + store_account_data.to_s
```

String interpolation is much more forgiving; it basically calls `to_s` for you:

```
puts "#{key} : #{store_account_data}"
```

Or perhaps you want a more detailed dump:

```
puts "#{key} : #{store_account_data.inspect}"
```

Or no brackets:

```
puts "#{key} : #{store_account_data.join(', ')}"
```

Or perhaps elements of `store_account_data` are objects, and you want to just print one property of them:

```
puts "#{key} : #{store_account_data.map(&:field_to_print).join(', '}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
def display(database)
  database.sDB.each do |key, account|
    puts "#{key}: #{account.join(',')}"
  end
end
```

Comment: this is perfect! thank you it worked. however, it doesnt seem to listing all of my database entries, it only lists one record, any idea why it could be doing that? @spickermann

Comment: Are you sure that your database (or the `database.sDB`) actually holds more records? You may try `puts database.sDB.size` or `puts database.sDB.inspect` to test that.

Comment: it is storing multiple records, so thats good. It must be a problem with me looping through them?

i added my code that i am looping through my hash with.

@spickermann

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby's [join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) method. I believe that's pretty common among languages.